# Weight Matrices for RNN One-to-Many Architecture

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network

It's my understanding that there are 3 weight matrices for RNNs - The one connected to the input, the one connected to the previous time-step activations and the one connected to the output.  But for on-to-many architectures it looks like the output for the previous time step becomes the input for the next timestep and there is no input from the previous timestep activations (at least that's what it looks like in [this image](https://images.app.goo.gl/LSHMUeZjpsMNpJdS7)).  Does this mean there are only 2 weight matrices for the one-to-many architecture i.e. the one connected to the input and the one connected to the output?